Используя Selenium с подгруженным профилем выполняется не вся программа
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\RobotComp.ru\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\RobotComp.ru\\.nuget\\packages\\selenium.webdriver.chromedriver\\126.0.6478.12600\\driver\\win32\\chromedriver.exe", options);

Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com"); 
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500);

IWebElement inputSearch = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-label='Введите запрос']"));
IWebElement sendSearch = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@aria-label='Введите запрос']"));
inputSearch.SendKeys("Текст");
sendSearch.Click();

Когда я использовал стандартный профиль хрома, программа работала отлично, а с подгруженным профилем она лишь выполняет переход на сайт и дальше не выполняет поиск элементов. Адблок и тд удалил, но не помогает. Что делать?

Не выполняет с ошибкой? не выполняет потому что его нет? А он точно на странице есть? В дев тулс его находит? Больше инфы.

ну когда я с дефолт профилем делаю он все находит, я перепроверял с профилем и в дев тулс все xpath совпадают

в процессе выполнения ошибок не выдает

Ну выведите html страницы в логи, да посмотрите что не так

я не знаю, на других сайтах почему-то работает а на ютубе  нет, может быть защита какая-то есть
